# Jquery Ajax Post to delete a file on server + asp .net mvc + c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, post

Hi I have been trying to create a link which on delete a pic stored on server and removes the information from the database. I want the link to be posted using ajax. I have tried everything but it does not work.

However, it works if I am trying to do something else other than delete - say update a field in database.

Can you tell me what is it that I am doing wrong?

View:

```
<div class="uploaded-property-pics clearfix">
    <ul>
        @foreach (var item in Model.PropertyPhotos) {
            <li>
                <img src="@Url.Content("~/PropertyImages/" + item.PropertyId + "/" + "tn_" + item.PhotoLocation + ".png")"/>
                <a href="/Property/DeletePhoto/@item.PropertyPhotosId" class="photo-delete-link">Delete</a>
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
<script>
    $('.photo-delete-link').click(function (e) {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.href,
            dataType: "text json",
            type: "POST",
            data: {},
            success: function (data, textStatus) { }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    public void DeletePhoto(int id)
    {
        var photo = websiteRepository.GetPhotoByPhotoId(id);
        var folder = Server.MapPath("~/PropertyImages/" + photo.PropertyId + "/");

        if (!Directory.Exists(folder))
        {
            var filePath = folder + photo.PhotoLocation + ".png";
            var thumbPath = folder + "tn_" + photo.PhotoLocation + ".png";
            websiteRepository.DeletePhotoFromServer(filePath);
            websiteRepository.DeletePhotoFromServer(thumbPath);
        }

        websiteRepository.DeletePhotoFromDb(photo);
    }
```

Data Access:

```
    public void DeletePhotoFromDb(PropertyPhotos photo)
    {
        db.PropertyPhotos.Remove(photo);
    }

    public void DeletePhotoFromServer(string filePath) 
    {
        File.Delete(filePath);
    }
```

Comment: How is the controller being passed the ID property?

Comment: Doesnt it pick it up from the route maps - it has worked for other similar ajax post that I have. I am trying the suggestion by Sanja though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is as stupid as it gets!

Subtle condition error:

```
if (Directory.Exists(folder)) // Note the subtle condition difference
        {
            var filePath = folder + photo.PhotoLocation + ".png";
            var thumbPath = folder + "tn_" + photo.PhotoLocation + ".png";
            websiteRepository.DeletePhotoFromServer(filePath);
            websiteRepository.DeletePhotoFromServer(thumbPath);
        }
```

As for the db part, I was not saving the database:

```
public void DeletePhotoFromDb(PropertyPhotos photo)
    {
        db.PropertyPhotos.Remove(photo);
        db.SaveChanges(); // Missing this line
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass argument to your controller method

```
$.ajax({
            url: this.href,//check this.href in debugger
            dataType: "text json",
            type: "POST",
            data: {Id: Id }, //pass argument here
            success: function (data, textStatus) { }
        });
```

Comment: Not sure about this because my current method works if say I have to change the name of the file on the db vs deleting it - using the same controller action

Comment: Doesn´t work .. I have put the @item.PropertyPhotosId in id of the a tag. And nothing still the same issue.

Comment: Yes, I did a alert(this.href) and it is correct. I am trying to see if I can catch anything in fiddler.. because it works for other database manipulation like websiterepository.MakeMainPic - it makes me question whether the error is with File.Delete and db.PropertyPhotos.Remove(photo)

Comment: the url in fiddler is /Property/Edit/Property/DeletePhoto - any suggestions to correct this?

Comment: @Tripping /Property/DeletePhoto (Controller/Action/arguments)

Comment: yup .. I dont know why that was happening but it is correct now that I have taken the id of 'a' tag out.